# About angular api call and component communication

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-router, angular-httpclient

I have a component product.component.ts in which i have all data of multiple product which i got by api call

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-pinfo',
    templateUrl: './product.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
  })
```

then after displaying all porduct on this component when i click the single product ,I navigate to detailedproductinfo component and i pass product id as navigation parameter i am intrested in know that what i do for detailed data about product from following

1. Api call to getproductinfobyid(id) or
2. pass data from  product component because i have already product related data in product component

I am intrested in know that which method will enhance performance  from above and what take time more in angular from below

1. passing data between component by using service or
2. api call by using http

Comment: for sure, use shared service or @input annotation for data you want to pass to child component

Comment: If you already have all the data you need in memory it's obviously faster to just pass it to another component than reloading it again from an external source.

Comment: i am not using detailedproductinfo as child component  it is completely independent component  @VinkoVorih

Comment: As earlier mentioned, if you have the data already, just pass it to the component. However, you can speed up everything further if you download only a list of product names and ids in your `product` component. At the time you want to display a specific product use you `getproductinfobyid`. However, this depends on the size of the product entity and the number of products. You do not have to download all products with all information if not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are multiple ways of dealing with this, it completely depends on these things:

1. Whether the Products API return the complete details for each product. Or whether they just return the relevant details based on what you'd like to show on the Product List Page.
2. Whether the Products API is in your control and you decide what data it is supposed to return.
3. The number of fields that the data model for each product has.

Keeping all this in mind, if the number of fields is quite a lot for each product, then I don't think it's appropriate to return the details of all the products via the `products` API. The specific details for each product should be returned by `products/:id` API which would take `ProductId` as a param.

So in this case, getting the Id from the `ActivatedRoute` and then calling `/products/:id` API to get the Product Details would make more sense.

If on the other hand, the data model for a product is not that big, it's totally fine to return the complete details of the products via the products API.

So in this case, passing the selected product data via a SharedService would be the approach to go for.